# What is uuidgen?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

Currently Starting learning API & Ajax to use public API app with jQuery & HTML and now I've been encountered unknown intelligence and that is why I would like everyone to help me here...

When I tried to use todoist API, he require uuidgen to use tasks update and since i don't know what is "uuidgen" so i have searched at uuidgen but even so, i still don't understand what is this and how to make & use it with jQuery...

[Require from todoist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEWGV.png)

So could anyone explain what this is and how to send `POST` to todoist API with uuidgen for update task?

kindly advises...

Comment: In addition, I am not mature means beginner so please explain to me as you teach to child....

Comment: http://developer.todoist.com/rest/v1/#update-a-task

Comment: Start reading from the top of the page your image has as the url: https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v1/#overview  *Each modification request may provide additional X-Request-Id HTTP header that could be used as an unique string to ensure modifications are applied only once*

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java-jar which you can download here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/uuidgen/

Use it like this

```
java -jar uuidgen.jar
```

If you don't need the company-message, just use it like this:

```
java -jar uuidgen.jar -q
```